# SUM the NUMC field in SELECT

Tags: group-by, abap, opensql

I need to group a table by the sum of a NUMC-column, which unfortunately seems not to be possible with ABAP / OpenSQL.

My code looks like that:

```
    SELECT z~anln1
    FROM zzanla AS z
    INTO TABLE gt_
    GROUP BY z~anln1 z~anln2
    HAVING SUM( z~percent ) <> 100  " percent unfortunately is a NUMC -> summing up not possible
```

What would be the best / easiest practices here as I cannot alter the table itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a smooth solution.
What I did, was to copy everything in an internal table, looped over it converting the NUMC values to DEC values. Grouping and summing up worked at that point.
At the end, I converted the DEC values back to NUMC values.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the `NUMC` type is described as numerical text, so at the end it lands in the database as `VARCHAR` and that is why the functions like `SUM` or `AVG` cannot be used.

It all depends on how big your table is. If it is rather small you could get the group fields and the values for sum into an internal table and then sum it using [`COLLECT`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abapcollect.htm) statement and eventually remove the rows for which the sum is equal 100%.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to define the field in the table using a more appropriate type.

NUMC is often used for key fields - like document numbers, which there would never be a reason to add together.

Comment: It probably was a mistake to define the field as a NUMC. But there are to many programs built around it to change it with justifiable efford.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile. I came back to this post, because someone voted up my original answer. I was thinking about editing my old answer but I decided to post a new one. As this question was asked in 2017, there were some restictions but now it can be done by using `CAST` function in new OpenSQL.

```
SELECT z~anln1
FROM zzanla AS z
INTO TABLE @gt_
GROUP BY z~anln1, z~anln2
HAVING SUM( CAST( z~percent AS INT4 ) ) <> 100
```